# Completely replace main monitor with external monitor Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, mojave, restart

I have a Macbook Pro 8,1 running macOS Mojave (I used a patch to get it, the warranty was already expired). I hooked it up to an external monitor, but when it restarts or when I shut it down and try to power it up again, the login is not displayed on the monitor. I have to login on the laptop, then the monitor displays a white screen before showing the opened computer. When I log out or it goes to sleep it acts as expected. Is there any way to fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Unlikely. The major blocker to your machine being actually capable of running Mojave was its GPU, so you're running it beyond its capacity anyway. Whatever patches it to fool the OS into thinking it's actually Metal-capable is unlikely to load until after the login screen.

Comment: It wasn't working before the patch, either. Just included it in case it was important.

Comment: So it's a graphics hardware issue unrelated to running Mojave on an unsupported device. What have you already tried yourself (e.g. changing cables, changing monitors, resetting NVRAM etc)?

Comment: All of the above. It is more of a umbrella Mac question, since it also happens on a friend's Mac.

Comment: Which screen is actually set as Primary? tbh, I don't know how that works for laptops, I've never owned one. On desktops it will present login on whichever screen you have assigned primary in Displays prefs, by dragging the little white menu bar to the chosen screen. https://i.stack.imgur.com/nE53C.png

Comment: The monitor was. I am not quite sure how I did it, but somehow I did something that fixed it. Is there any way to close a question without an answer?

Comment: We could all just walk away, whistling innocently, & pretend it never happened :P Seriously, if it just 'magically fixed itself' then leave it in abeyance for now & see if it happens again, then see if you can tell what happened to fix it. if a pattern eventually forms, that may be the answer.

Comment: Alright sounds good. Yeah, it just magically happened. It has been happening for more than a year so it will probably pop up again :)